# In Scrapy, can't extract text of a link with a "@" in it

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

In the Scrapy shell for the URL http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/sony-mobile-communications/foldinghome/foldinghome-1-00-40-release/foldinghome-1-00-40-android-apk-download/, I'm trying to extract the developer, app, and version names from the navigation bar:

[image]

I've tried the following XPath selector:

```
In [6]: response.xpath('//*[@class="breadcrumbs"]//a/text()').extract()
Out[6]: [u'Sony Mobile Communications', u'1.00.40']
```

However, notice that the app name, `Folding@Home`, is not among the results. I do not understand this because it does seem to have an `<a>` tag (as shown using "Inspect" in Chrome):

[image]

Moreover, for a similar site, http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/oculus-vr/oculus-rooms/oculus-rooms-0-0-2-release/oculus-rooms-0-0-2-android-apk-download/, this selector does work:

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//*[@class="breadcrumbs"]//a/text()').extract()
Out[1]: [u'Oculus VR', u'Oculus Rooms', u'0.0.2']
```

I am beginning to suspect that this might be some kind of bug in Scrapy whereby it does not select the `text()` of `<a>` elements with `@` symbols. Might this be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already figured out, one of the breadcrumb links is "protected" and is dynamically constructed via JavaScript executed in the browser.

One easy way to approach the problem would be to pass the content of the page through `Splash` via [`scrapy-splash`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) middleware. This worked for me:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class ApkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "apkmirror"
    allowed_domains = ['apkmirror.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
            'http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/sony-mobile-communications/foldinghome/foldinghome-1-00-40-release/foldinghome-1-00-40-android-apk-download/',
            self.parse_result,
            )

    def parse_result(self, response):
        print(response.xpath('//*[@class="breadcrumbs"]//a/text()').extract())
```

with the following settings:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8050'
SPLASH_COOKIES_DEBUG = True

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'

HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

and `Splash` running in a docker container on the port `8050`.

Prints:

```
[u'Sony Mobile Communications', u'Folding@Home', u'1.00.40']
```

Answer (score 1):

Viewing the page source using Chrome's "View Page Source" option instead of "Inspect", I see that the navigation bar for this particular link contains JavaScript:

```
<nav style="margin-left:16px; margin-right:16px;" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div style="color: #013967 !important;" class="breadcrumbs"><a class="withoutripple" style="color: #013967 !important;" href="/apk/sony-mobile-communications/">Sony Mobile Communications</a> <svg class="icon chevron-icon"><use xlink:href="#apkm-icon-chevron"></use></svg> <a class="withoutripple " style="color: #013967 !important;" href="/apk/sony-mobile-communications/foldinghome/"><span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="c781a8aba3aea9a0878fa8aaa2">[email&#160;protected]</span><script data-cfhash='f9e31' type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */!function(t,e,r,n,c,a,p){try{t=document.currentScript||function(){for(t=document.getElementsByTagName('script'),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute('data-cfhash'))return t[e]}();if(t&&(c=t.previousSibling)){p=t.parentNode;if(a=c.getAttribute('data-cfemail')){for(e='',r='0x'+a.substr(0,2)|0,n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)e+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(n,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(decodeURIComponent(e)),c)}p.removeChild(t)}}catch(u){}}()/* ]]> */</script></a> <svg class="icon chevron-icon"><use xlink:href="#apkm-icon-chevron"></use></svg> <a class="active withoutripple" style="color: #013967 !important;" href="/apk/sony-mobile-communications/foldinghome/foldinghome-1-00-40-release/">1.00.40</a> </nav>
```

whereas for the Oculus Rooms page in the second example it doesn't:

```
<nav style="margin-left:16px; margin-right:16px;" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div style="color: #646464 !important;" class="breadcrumbs"><a class="withoutripple" style="color: #646464 !important;" href="/apk/oculus-vr/">Oculus VR</a> <svg class="icon chevron-icon"><use xlink:href="#apkm-icon-chevron"></use></svg> <a class="withoutripple " style="color: #646464 !important;" href="/apk/oculus-vr/oculus-rooms/">Oculus Rooms</a> <svg class="icon chevron-icon"><use xlink:href="#apkm-icon-chevron"></use></svg> <a class="active withoutripple" style="color: #646464 !important;" href="/apk/oculus-vr/oculus-rooms/oculus-rooms-0-0-2-release/">0.0.2</a> </nav>
```

Handling JavaScript with Scrapy is a known issue (cf. https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/).